# Which one is the best target to migrate an ASP.NET project, .Net Core or .Net Standard?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

Please do not consider this as a duplicated question. I'm going to migrate my **`ASP.NET RESTful web-api`** (.Net Full) project to `.Net Standard` or `.Net Core` and I faced a serious question which I could not find the answer in other similar questions.

What I'm looking of this question is to realize while I can choose `.Net Core`, Why should I target my library assemblies on `.Net Standard`?

Maybe one reason is to keep these assemblies ready to use them in a `.Net Framework` project. Regardless of this, Is there any other reason to convince me to keep my target on `.Net Standard`?

**Note:** I do not need to keep `.Net Full` version of my project I just want to have a `cross-platform` version of it.

---

Comment: I assume .Net Core has less built in libraries. You really need to list all of your constraints. Is the only constraint that you need to have a cross platform version? By cross platform do you mean x86 and x64?

Comment: Yes, libraries should be .NET Standard so they can work under Core or Framework.

Comment: .NET Standard is only for libraries. The runtime is .NET Core. Your choices are *only* Full or .NET Core. If you want cross-platform, that's .NET Core. `ASP.NET Core` itself runs on both runtimes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no choice to make. .NET Standard is only meant for .NET Class libraries. It's not a runtime so one can't create applications that target it. The runtimes are .NET Core and .NET Full framework.

.NET Core is the only cross-platform option.

ASP.NET Core itself is a web stack that can run on *both* runtimes. You can pick the one you want in the `New Project` dialog.

When it comes to libraries, the choice depends on what's needed. .NET Standard libraries can target any compatible runtime. ASP.NET Core's own [Razor Class Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) are .NET Standard 2.0 projects. Most NuGet packages are .NET Standard-compatible to avoid the hassle of packaging different versions for every runtime.

On the other hand, the latest Span-related features appear only in .NET Core 2.1 and later. They [aren't available in .NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.op_implicit?view=netcore-2.2) but they *will* appear in 2.1. This sample from [All About Span: Exploring a New .NET Mainstay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) would only work in .NET Core 2.1+ :

```
string input = ...;
ReadOnlySpan<char> inputSpan = input;
int commaPos = input.IndexOf(',');
int first = int.Parse(inputSpan.Slice(0, commaPos));
int second = int.Parse(inputSpan.Slice(commaPos + 1));
```

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis, That was really helpful